# How do I bring an old Blue Imp Gallery script up to date and get it working again?

Tags: gallery, blueimp

I have a site that I took over that includes Blue imp galleries but they have stopped working - when you click on the thumbnail link the screen just becomes black without any images and you need to refresh to view the page again.

Here is a link to the page that contains the galleries: https://www.secrethillswalking.co.uk/holiday/746/1240/a-yorkshire-treat---hebden-bridge.htm

What code do I need to remove/add to get both the galleries showing the larger images properly again?

I have tried just replacing jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js with the new version but this did not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your page's source code and I think you're missing the javascript to bring blueimp into play for the PHOTO GALLERY section. This is what I use:

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement
    var link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target
    var options = { index: link, event: event }
    var links = this.getElementsByTagName('a')
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options)
  }
```

where 'links' is the id of your gallery div.